# Second monitor won't work at correct resolution onToshiba Satellite P50-C with (GeForce GTX 950m) on Ubuntu 19.10 (works fine in Windows 10)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

I have installed Ubuntu 19.10 side by side (in dual boot) with Windows 10. Everything works perfectly, except for dual monitor setup. When I connect my AOC 32" monitor with HDMI cable that has optimal resolution of 2560×1440, there is no image on that monitor. If I lower the resolution to 1920×1080 and then the monitor works, but everything is blurry and too big. On Windows everything is working alright, so this is not a hardware issue.

I've tried playing with the display refresh rate, because I read somewhere that that resolution (2560×1440) only works with 30 Hz refresh rate, but I am not able to select 30 Hz on that monitor in display settings. It only allows me to select some strange decimal number refresh rates, e.g. 63.67 and 75.23. But none of that works.

My computer is laptop Toshiba Satellite P50-C. There are two graphic cards inside, Intel's integrated graphics and nVidia GeForce GTX 950m. I have already searched for solutions online, but I didn't manage to make it work. When I open Ubuntu About app there it says that GeForce is the video card that is used by Ubuntu.

Also, I've updated to the latest nVidia proprietary drivers and I've tried different drivers (different versions), but with no result. I would really like to switch fully to Ubuntu but this is a deal-breaker for me.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in exactly the same situation as you.  Geoforce GTX 1080 and Acer CB270HU monitor.  Everything works perfectly in Windows 10 but in Ubuntu 19.10 only my two Samsung Monitors work, the Acer one flickers very noticeably.

Edit: I tried Linux Mint 19.3. With Cinnamon it doesn’t work, but with the MATE desktop it does! No more flicker!

Comment: I've read somewhere that Linux Mint has support for HiDpi screens, so I will try that distro ... Hopefully, Ubuntu 20 will add support for HiDPI displays.

Comment: @Tjodalv, did you have any luck with that? I'm considering doing the same.

Comment: I didn't have a chance to try it or do anything about it really, because of corona quarantine. HiDPI monitor is in the office where I work. Currently I am at home, so I cannot experiment with it ... At home I am using 24" HD monitor and that monitor works ok.

Comment: I tried it last night. With Linux Mint 19.3 MATE it works perfectly (but not with Cinnamon). Thank you @Tjodalv!

Comment: Does Linux Mint MATE support different scaling for each of the monitors you have connected? That is also not currently supported in Ubuntu. In Ubuntu you can change scaling but it will scale on all monitors the same.

Comment: Yes it does. I have 1920x1080 on one monitor and 1920x1200 on the other two

Answer (score 0):

On clean Ubuntu 18.04 I had to use GNOME extension to get 3 monitors working correctly: [Multi Monitors Add-On](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/921/multi-monitors-add-on/)

Still, occasionally I encountered some errors, like broken resolution and secondary monitors not working at all. Most if not all of them became non-existent after switching to [KDE Plasma](https://kde.org/plasma-desktop) desktop.

If anyone has an issue with a **flickering** monitor, I recommend experimenting with the screen **refresh rate**.

If display settings on your distro are not sufficient, try [xrandr](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr). Example code to change refresh rate:

`xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 60`

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

1. Enable Virtual machine platform in the Windows Features (Control panel > Turn Windows features on or off)
2. Enable virtual machines in the UEFI Firmware Settings